# Firebase oAuth popup getting blocked on Firefox Mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

Problem: Firebase google signin is working on chrome but not on firefox due to popup blocker.

I have a react application that uses Firebase oAuth ( Google / Apple ) for authenticating users. I am using the following function to accomplish this:

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
```

The use-case of me wanting to use oAuth is to get the `idToken`, which I'll send to my backend for further verifications. I am doing this as I don't want oAuth verification to be self-sufficient ( i.e. I still want to confirm with my backend whether I have this user in my database and add some more checks that I don't want to expose on the client-side ). I have packed my oAuth functions in a class as follows:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
const { Auth, OAuthProvider, GoogleAuthProvider } = firebase.auth;

export default class OAuth {
    async getToken(withProvider) {
        await firebase.auth().setPersistence(Auth.Persistence.NONE);
        await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(withProvider);
        const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
        await firebase.auth().signOut();
        return token;
    }

    getGoogleProvider() { return new GoogleAuthProvider(); }

    getAppleProvider() { return new OAuthProvider('apple.com'); }
}
```

Later on, I am using these functions in an React component as follows:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import View from "./views";

import Session from "utils/session";
import OAuth from "utils/session/oAuth";

import getAuthToken from "utils/api/auth/getAuthToken";

export default function SignIn() {
    const [oAuth] = useState(new OAuth());

    const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(null);
    const [oAuthToken, setOAuthToken] = useState(null);

    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!oAuthToken) return;
        getAuthToken(oAuthToken).then(setAuthToken).catch(setError);
    }, [oAuthToken]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!authToken) return;

        Session.initialize(authToken).catch(setError);
    }, [authToken]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!error) return;
        // Notify user of the error
    }, [error]);

    const oAuthSignIn = provider => {
        oAuth.getToken(provider).then(setOAuthToken).catch(setError);
    };

    const signInWithApple = event => {
        oAuthSignIn(oAuth.getAppleProvider());
    };

    const signInWithGoogle = event => {
        oAuthSignIn(oAuth.getGoogleProvider());
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={signInWithApple}>Apple</button>
            <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Google</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This auth-flow works just fine on chrome ( pc / mobile ), safari ( pc / mobile ), and firefox ( pc ). But the issue is that this doesn't work on Firefox Mobile. What happens is when I click on any button, firefox asks whether to allow pop-up or not. But even before user action is complete the function `setError` is executed indicating that the oAuth function `oAuth.getToken` has failed. Can anyone please explain why is this happening?